# PyTorch training file - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: pytorch

When I run the following code:

```
...
    if write and is_train:
        train_loss_file.write(
            "[%d], Loss:%.5f, Loss(VecMap):%.5f, Pixel Accuracy:%.3f, Mean Accuracy:%.3f, Mean IoU:%.3f, Class IoU:[%.5f/%.5f], Freq.Weighted Accuray:%.3f  \n"
            % (
                epoch,
                loss,
                loss_vec,
                100 * pixel_accuracy,
                100 * np.nanmean(mean_accuracy),
                100 * np.nanmean(mean_iou),
                mean_iou[0],
                mean_iou[1],
                (100 * fwavacc),
            )
        )
...
```

I get the following error:

```
[>....... 1/1 ............]S:25s968ms|T:0ms|Loss: -0.199331 | VecLoss: 3.783525 | road miou: 17.2746%(18.3798%) | angle miou: 0.2103%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_mtl.py", line 443, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_mtl.py", line 434, in main
    train(epoch)
  File "train_mtl.py", line 294, in train
    write=True,
  File "C:\Users\...\road_connectivity-master\utils\util.py", line 147, in performMetrics
    (100 * fwavacc),
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can you please help me overcome this issue?
The code is retrieved from this repository: https://github.com/anilbatra2185/road_connectivity
I am discussing with the contributor, but we cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Where did you define `fwavacc`? What's the link for the code? I understand the error, but I can't help you unless I know what you've been doing.

Comment: That's why I gave you the URL of the repository that I have been using, so that you can check any part of the code that you would like. If you go at the util.py file inside the utils folder, you can find the definition of the fwavacc which is:
fwavacc = (freq[freq > 0] * mean_iou[freq > 0]).sum()